# memory leak with passing any object

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have a question about android memory leak.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyClass m = new MyClass();
    m.setListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}

}

public class MyClass {

private static  View.OnClickListener listener;

public void setListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
   this.listener = listener;
}
}
```

may it make a  memory leak? if yes why? is it a good  technique  to passing a  listener?

Answer (score 1):

**Static fields** are potentially dangerous because they can be referenced by `Actvities` and other objects causing most of our memory leaks problems.

Lifetime of static object is equal to application lifetime that means it will be live until application is running and can not be collected before application is finished. You made basic example of memory leak.

`Views` are related to `Activity` and strongly hold reference to it, but as you declared it as `private static View.OnClickListener listener` it will leak.

Comment: if I did not declare it static?  may it leak?

Comment: can activity dealloc? if we define  listener by non static

Comment: `Views` should never be declared as `static` but it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I mean that sending data with new Activity(new OnClickListeener() { @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

        }})   like this.this way is bad or  good?. also can it make a  leak for first activity?. can it  prevent  first activities  g. collected?

Comment: If you want to pass data between `Activities` use `Intent`, if you want to pass data between `Activity` and `Fragment` than you can use `interface`. Take a look into that how you can pass data between `Activity` and `Activity` or `Activity` and `Fragment`